# How can I change input to span in Datapicker?

Tags: jquery, input, datepicker

How can I make the date selected in the datapicker show in a span and not in an input?

`<input type="text" id="datep" />  => <span id="datep"></span>`

Comment: Just for clarity, which datepicker? There's a jquery ui datepicker, there's a bootstrap datepicker, and plenty more random ones.

Comment: Datepicker (jQuery UI)
In the <input> should appear the date that was selected in the calendar that is below. Actually this field is only for the result. In this case, how would be the correct way to show the selected date within the span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML

```
<span id="showdate">Here you can show the selected date</span><br/>
<label>Date Picker:</label>
<div  id="date" class="date" ></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy ",
        onSelect: function (d) {
            $('#showdate').text(d);
        }
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shervini/xbzjfu24/6/)

Comment: Datepicker (jQuery UI) In the <input> should appear the date that was selected in the calendar that is below. Actually this field is only for the result. In this case, how would be the correct way to show the selected date within the span?

Comment: @trascer where do you want to display calendar?in this case any value in input will be empty and span will display

Comment: Code is: 
`<div id="a"></div>
<input type="text" id="b" />`

#a = calendar
#b = selected date

I need covert input #b to span #b

Comment: @trascer check out the new answer.It converts the new value to span if you don't want to display input after selecting the date you can fadeout input.

Comment: @trascer as you said the selected date will display in span

Comment: It works perfect Shervin, but I need the calendar to be always open without the input field... it´s possible? `inline: true` it does not work.

Comment: Perfect, I found the solution, instead of **input**, use a **div**. Thank you very much Shervin!

Comment: @trascer Check the link again